# How to unambiguously quote when printing all args passed to a bash function? But taking care to quote special characters, avoid using the backslash?

Tags: bash, escaping, echo, special-characters, quotes

Basically I need a shell function called echo_Q (or an `echo -Q` option), than will echo a quoted argument list, while "<s>[nicely]</s>" strictly avoiding any backslash-quoting on any of the arguments, if possible.

A raw example of the native `echo` with some problem arguments:

```
echo another_script a "b b" "c 'c' c" 'd "d" d' "e "'"'"'e'"'"'" e" "ls -ltrd .??* | sort -k5,5 > f.lst" 'file `ls -t $HOME`' '|' '&' ';' "<"
```

Naturally, the native `echo` produces:

```
another_script a b b c 'c' c d "d" d e "'e'" e ls -ltrd .??* | sort -k5,5 > f.lst file `ls -t $HOME` | & ; <
```

In the above result: The quotes have have been evaluated, where necessary spaces and quotes have become opaque.

I've tried, `printf " %q" "$@"; echo`, and even:

```
echo_q(){
    sep="";
    for arg in "$@"; do
        printf "$sep%q" "$arg"
        sep=" "
    done
    echo
}
```

And get a fully "escaped" (verbose) output, where quoting is totally avoided.

```
echo_q another_script a "b b" etc..

another_script a b\ b c\ \'c\'\ c d\ \"d\"\ d e\ \"\'e\'\"\ e ls\ -ltrd\ .\?\?\*\ \|\ sort\ -k5\,5\ \>\ f.lst file\ \`ls\ -t\ \$HOME\` \| \& \; \>
```

In the above result: The output is technically what I want, but kind of "unpleasant" to read due to all the backslashes.

I would prefer (for readability) the output of:

```
another_script a 'b b' "c 'c' c" 'd "d" d' e\ \"\'e\'\"\ e 'ls -ltrd .??* | sort -k5,5 > f.lst' 'file `ls -t $HOME`' '|' '&' ';' '>'
```

Here is a "simple" *hack* I have been dabbling with:

```
special='$( )*?`<>\\|&;'
qq_special='$`'

echo_Q(){
    sep="";
    for arg in "$@"; do
        printf "$sep";
        sep=" "
        case "$arg" in
        (*["$special'"'"']*)
            case "$arg" in
            (*'"'*)
                case "$arg" in
                    (*"'"*)printf "%q" "$arg";;
                    (*)printf "'%s'" "$arg";;
                esac;;
            (*"'"*)
                case "$arg" in
                    (*"$qq_special"*) printf "%q" "$arg";;
                    (*) printf '"%s"' "$arg";;
                esac;;
            (*) printf "'%s'" "$arg";;
            esac;;
        (*) printf "%s" "$arg";;
        esac
        sep=" "
    done
    echo
}
```

But I'm hoping there is a standard (and simpler) way to "nicely" `echo` a function's arguments...

Bash does have: `printf "%q"`, but what I need is a `printf "%Q"` to nicely quote an argument.  Sadly, something so simple eludes me. :-(

Hints welcomed!

Comment: What is your exact input set of words, that are you dealing with?

Comment: eg. ```echo_Q another_script a "b b" "c 'c' c" 'd "d" d' "e "'"'"'e'"'"'" e" "ls -ltrd .??* | sort -k5,5 > f.lst" 'file `ls -t $HOME`' '|' '&' ';' "<" ```

Comment: I think you need to define your understanding of the word **nicely**.  You seem to love quotes, but dislike backslashes. The alternative you showed as acceptable however also contains backslashes. You seem to look for a very specific pretty-printer for variables. Perhaps you simply need to implement one.

Comment: re: ```def nicely(): ... ```

In the simplest case, **never** use a back-slash, unless there is no other way.

Alternatively, use a single-quote (') or a double-quoting ("), unless unless "back-slash quoting" the argument is 4 characters shorter. 

Actually, I was hoping was "quote quoting" was just already built into ```bash``` ... And I'd just not found it! ;-)

Comment: Part of the problem here is that "nicely" is subjective (and because it requires more judgments, is likely slower than `printf %q` or `${…@Q}` expansion).  Whereas "usable as input" is an objective functional specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash does support a way to quote a parameter in a way that can be re-used as an input agin. Parameter expansion `${parameter@operator}` supports a flag (introduced on bash v4.4)

> Q
> The expansion is a string that is the value of parameter quoted in a format that can be reused as input.

```bash
set -- a "b b" "c 'c' c" 'd "d" d' "e "'"'"'e'"'"'" e" "ls -ltrd .??* | sort -k5,5 > f.lst" 'file `ls -t $HOME`' '|' '&' ';' "<"
for arg in "$@"; do
    printf '%s\n' "${arg@Q}"
done
```

produces

```bash
'a'
'b b'
'c '\''c'\'' c'
'd "d" d'
'e "'\''e'\''" e'
'ls -ltrd .??* | sort -k5,5 > f.lst'
'file `ls -t $HOME`'
'|'
'&'
';'
'<'
```

Comment: No need to loop over it just do: `${@@Q}` and for custom arrays it would be `${arr[@]@Q}`

Comment: @Ivan True, used it for demonstration only.

Comment: Nice: However did you find "${arg@Q}"? ...  `man bash` is as big as a 150-page paperback novel.

Comment: @NevilleDNZ - It comes out of practice, you need to know, what you are looking for - https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion (at the bottom)

Comment: It is a bit sad that ```"c 'c' c"```  gets encoded as ```'c '\''c'\'' c'```.  But I'm not complaining.

Comment: Yeah, as said, the way it is encoded above, it is safe to re-use it again in shell context. If you are looking for a specific format style, perhaps re-writing your own quoting logic should be the way

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you're trying to do is execute a command with some quoted arguments, but then also print it out somewhere in a way that looks nice including bash-style quoting. The previous poster's solution is nice, albeit it doesn't keep your original quoting. Here's a little snippet that might be of some use to you that keeps it exact:

```
$ read A <<eof
> a "b b" "c 'c' c" 'd "d" d' "e "'"'"'e'"'"'" e"
> eof
$ echo $A
a "b b" "c 'c' c" 'd "d" d' "e "'"'"'e'"'"'" e"
$ eval echo $A
a b b c 'c' c d "d" d e "'e'" e
printx() {
> for i in "$@"
> do
> echo "$i"
> done
> }
$ eval printx $A
a
b b
c 'c' c
d "d" d
e "'e'" e
```